# Cant Plot Different Types of Variables from a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, algorithm, plot, statistics

Hello So I have a Data frame which has a variable Email and a Variable grade_d which has values of A B C D E. I wanna make a plot where Ι can see How many people(from email variable) where A, B, etc...

Comment: It work but in Y axis the Students ( Emails ) are Like:
12.5
10.0
7.5
5
But i want the numbers showing From 0 to 50 , 100, 150, 200, to 264 ( All the emails)

Comment: I recommend you to read some documentation about data wrangling in R and the documentation about the ggplot2 package, because your question is more like a learning session about R rather than a specific problem where u stuck with. I recommend the ggplot2 homepage: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/ for plotting and the dplyr homepage: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ for data wrangling.

Comment: Yeah you are right I will Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example with a bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(e_mail=c("a@abc.com", "b@.abc.com", "c@abc.com", "d@abc.com", "e@abc.com"),
                        grade_d=c("A", "B", "A", "E", "D"))

ggplot(test_data, aes(grade_d, fill=grade_d)) + geom_bar()
```

This will lead to:
[image]

Comment: Yes this works fine! But I have some Na's in Grade_d how can that be removed without changing Y axis? I Try to use !is.na(grade_d) but  I Get ERROR:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (264): x, fill

Comment: Use `test_data <- dplyr::filter(test_data, !is.na(grade_d))` to filter all Na's from your dataframe before plotting.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bar plot using either the normal R plot() function or ggplot.

For example:

```
    library(ggplot2)

email <- c("a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com", "c@gmail.com", "d@gmail.com")
grade <- c("A", "A", `enter code here`"B", "C")

data <- data.frame(email, grade)

ggplot(data, aes(x=grade)) + geom_bar() + labs(x="Grade")
```

What you get on the y axis is the count of people that got each grade.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(eMail = 1:100,
                 grade = LETTERS[sample(6, 100, replace = TRUE) ])

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = grade)) + stat_count()
```

[image]